# Using Raidrive and WSL2 together will cause \\wsl.localhost cannot be opened

Tags: windows, wsl-2

I am using **Raidrive** to mount **Alist** to my local hard drive. When I use Raidrive and **WSL2** at the same time,`\\wsl.localhost` cannot be opened.
It will pop up "***Do not have permission to use network resources, please contact your administrator***".

Uninstalling **Raidrive** will solve the problem. I wonder what caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Raidrive will set cbfs6 with the highest priority in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\HwOrder\ProviderOrder` every time it starts. However, in Windows 11, WSL2 has fully enabled P9NP. Suppose we don't delete cbfs6 in the reg, `\\wsl.localhost` cannot be opened.

Comment: Here is the discussion issued in Raidrive's forum.[https://with.raidrive.com/t/cbfs6-added-to-registry-editor-makes-wsl2-linux-tree-inaccessible/5177/2](https://with.raidrive.com/t/cbfs6-added-to-registry-editor-makes-wsl2-linux-tree-inaccessible/5177/2)